# Laravel blade array foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I'm trying to acces to the parameters of an array, and not been able to.
I get an array through this eloquent statement:

```
$plazas = DB::table('clase_schedule')->select(['schedule_id', DB::raw('SUM(capMax)')])->groupBy('schedule_id')->get();
```

What returns me this array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#465 ▼
    +"schedule_id": "2"
    +"SUM(capMax)": "221"
  }
  1 => {#464 ▼
    +"schedule_id": "3"
    +"SUM(capMax)": "12"
  }
]
```

I've tryed serveral things to acces to the schedule_id and SUM(capMax) values, but nothin.

```
@foreach($plazas as $id => $id)
{{$id[0]}}<br/>
@endforeach
```

With that i get the return value of 
    0
    1

Comment: @foreach($plazas as $plaza) 
{{$plaza->schedule_id}}
@endoreach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use alias to fetch query

```
$plazas = DB::table('clase_schedule')->select(['schedule_id', DB::raw('SUM(capMax) as capmax')])->groupBy('schedule_id')->get();
```

Blade

```
@foreach($plazas as $plaza)
{{ $plaza['capmax'] }}<br/>
@endforeach
```